# Trying to change the color of database and variable names

Tags: colors, sql-server-2012

I am customizing the colors and can't for the life of me find the option to change the color of database/table and variable names ..they are stuck that odd teal color, Ive changed the color of ever teal option i could find and yet they are still teal. Driving me crazy any help finding out what that is called would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnaly found it here, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e93ab1bc-114a-45cb-a708-3dcd20911b00/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-teal-sql-variable-names?forum=vssetup

basically it is the "Identifier" and even though it will show default as some other color it will show up as teal unless you change it.